# How to find the middle point of an arc slice?

Tags: geometry, polar-coordinates

I need to find centre of different arc in the Pie Chart. I have following details -

Similar question is here -
[How to find the middle point of an arc slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034520/how-to-find-the-middle-point-of-an-arc-slice)

here is the reference image from above post -

[image]

[image]

My Scenario. When I move to different slice I need to calculate centre of that slice. This is the piechart centre coordinates -

```
cx = 330.5;
cy = 140;
```

#### First (Green) slice details -

```
{
    "cx": 330.5,
    "cy": 140,
    "innerRadius": 0,
    "middleRadius": 54,
    "outerRadius": 108,
    "maxRadius": 352.3850876526985,
    "startAngle": 0,
    "endAngle": 17.358490566037737,
    "midAngle": 8.679245283018869,
    "paddingAngle": 0,
    "percent": 0.04821802935010482,
}
```

#### Second (Orange) slice details -

```
{
    "cx": 330.5,
    "cy": 140,
    "innerRadius": 0,
    "middleRadius": 54,
    "outerRadius": 108,
    "maxRadius": 352.3850876526985,
    "percent": 0.36547868623340324,
    "startAngle": 17.358490566037737,
    "midAngle": 83.14465408805033,
    "endAngle": 148.93081761006292,
    "paddingAngle": 0,
    "percent": 0.36547868623340324,
}
```

#### Third (Gray) slice details -

```
{
    "cx": 330.5,
    "cy": 140,
    "innerRadius": 0,
    "middleRadius": 54,
    "outerRadius": 108,
    "maxRadius": 352.3850876526985,
    "startAngle": 148.93081761006292,
    "midAngle": 254.46540880503147,
    "endAngle": 360,
    "paddingAngle": 0,
    "percent": 0.5863032844164919,
}
```

I tried following formula but it did not work and not getting the expected result -

```
x = cx + outerRadius * Math.cos(midAngle),
y = cy + outerRadius * Math.sin(midAngle),
```

#### Update

After changing the formula to

```
 x = cx + outerRadius * Math.cos(midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);
 y = cy + outerRadius * Math.sin(midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);
```

I am getting following output -
**Completed -**

```
{x: 437.2632503544796, y: 156.29749593485772}
```

[image]
**In progress -**

```
{x: 343.3912133107331, y: 247.2278723997505}
```

[image]
**Not started -**

```
{x: 301.5754291795817, y: 35.9453547271694}
```

[image]

You can see in all above three images tooltip position is not correct.

Comment: In most programming languages, cosine and sine functions take the angle in radians, where you obviously have it in degrees.  Try `(midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0)`.

Comment: @Glärbo I treid this but did not work.

Comment: In what way is it not behaving as you expect? Can you add some more images to your question so we can see the positions?

Comment: @JansthcirlU I have added some screenshots. As you can see those tooltips are not inside arc but outside. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It seems like the angle in the pie chart increases in the clockwise direction as opposed to the conventional anticlockwise direction. Try using `360 - midAngle` in your expressions, or if possible, make sure that the angle increases in the anticlockwise direction.

Comment: No, the angle increases counterclockwise: the green area starts at angle 0 and ends at angle 17.xxx degrees, then the organge area starts at 17.xxx and ends at 148.xxx and finally the gray area starts at 148.xxx and ends at 360.

Comment: IIUC, you want to find the coordinates of the point on the "midangle" of each sector and halfway between the center and the circumference - is that correct? You might want to edit the question and indicate (preferably by marking the point(s) whose coordinates you want on the image. In particular, adding the boxes with the labels does not help, because there is no precise indication of which points they are attached to.

Comment: Or maybe it's the point on the midangle and *on* the circumference? In which case, the calculation with radians seems correct and all you have to do is place the boxes correctly. I'd suggest you plot the points you calculated to make sure that they are correctly placed and worry about the boxes afterwards.

Comment: @NickD I feel you have got my point. For more clarification I have added the updated images. Please let me know if it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What seems to be the issue

[image]

To create the above image, I simply grabbed the descriptions at their calculated positions and superimposed them on top of the original pie chart. Then, I shaded the areas where it seems that the back-end *thinks* the positions are. As you can see, both description boxes are positioned at the midpoint of the (mirrored) shaded regions.

### How to interpret the image

It seems that the calculated angle increases in the clockwise direction, while the shown slices somehow still increase in the anticlockwise direction. In other words, when you tell it to show something at `midAngle = 8.679`, it thinks it should position it at an angle of `-8.679` or alternatively `351.321` degrees when using the conventions of the unit circle.

### What to change

To get the angle right in your program, simply change every occurrence of `midAngle` to `-midAngle`. In the comments I said changing your code to `360 - midAngle` could also work, but simply making it negative will result in the same thing.

Once you've got the angle, all you need to do is tweak how far along the radius (at said angle) the description box must appear. Currently you're using the full value of `outerRadius` to calculate the values of `x` and `y`, but as NickD says in his answer, you could use `0.5 * outerRadius` to make the boxes appear halfway the pie chart's radius.

In other words, this should work:

```
x = cx + 0.5 * outerRadius * Math.cos(-midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);
y = cy + 0.5 * outerRadius * Math.sin(-midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);
```

Although using `Math.cos(midAngle * ...)` would work just as well as `Math.cos(-midAngle * ...)`, because $cos(\theta)=cos(-\theta)$ for all values of $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the point on the midangle of the sector and halfway from the center to the circumference:

$$
x = x_c + \frac{1}{2}R\cos(\theta)
$$
$$
y = y_c + \frac{1}{2}R\sin(\theta)
$$
where $\theta$ is the midangle in radians. As the comments note, you convert the midangle in degrees (denoted by $\theta_{mid}^\circ$ below) to radians by dividing by 360 and multiplying by $2\pi$: $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{360}\theta_{mid}^\circ$.

In terms of your programming variables:

```
x = cx + 0.5 * outerRadius * Math.cos(midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);
y = cy + 0.5 * outerRadius * Math.sin(midAngle * 3.14159265358979323846 / 180.0);
```

although I would *at least*  define a constant `PI` instead of using 3.14.... in *two* places:

```
PI =  3.14159265358979323846
x = cx + 0.5 * outerRadius * Math.cos(midAngle * PI / 180.0)
y = cy + 0.5 * outerRadius * Math.sin(midAngle * PI / 180.0)
```

But as you can see the only difference with your formula is the halving of the radius.